# Convert one object type to another object type using RxJS

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have the following models:

```
export interface IdName { 
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

export interface Product { 
    id: number;
    name: string;
    currency?: string;
    additionalData: any;
}
```

I would like to convert Observable<Product[]> to Observable<IdName[]> in Angular/Typescript. I tried

```
getData() : Observable<IdName[]> {

        // Note: getProducts returns Observable<Product[]>

        this.productService.getProducts().pipe(
            return map((product: Product) => {
                {id: product.id, name: product.name}
            });
        );

    }
```

However, it shows some syntax errors. How can I fix it?

Comment: What are the errors?..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some typos, change to:

```
getData(): Observable<IdName[]> {
    return this.productService.getProducts().pipe(
       map((products: Product[]) => {

         return products.map(product => ({
           id: product.id,
           name: product.name
         } as IdName));
       })
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I am still getting the following error : "Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<Product, IdName>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<Product[], IdName>'.  Type 'Product' is not assignable to type 'Product[]'.  Property 'length' is missing in type 'Product'. (alias) interface Product
import Product"

Comment: @developer Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You misplaced the `return` statement and a semicolon.

It should be:

```js
return this.productService.getProducts().pipe(
  map((product: Product) => {
    return {id: product.id, name: product.name}
  })
);
```

`pipe()` takes a list (varargs) of operations defined as `operator(input => output)` or expanded `operator(input => { return output; })`

Comment: Thanks, it works after I added return this.productService...

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error in the usage of your arrow function and the RxJS `map` operator.

Note the following

```js
const Func = (param: Product) => ({ id: param.id, name: param.name })
```

is equivalent to

```js
const Func = (param: Product) => { 
  return { id: param.id, name: param.name }
};
```

---

I see the following issues:

1. The `return` statement is in the wrong place. The RxJS [`map`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/map) operator doesn't have explicitly return anything. It already returns the source observable containing the modified data.
2. The type signature is wrong. If it's an array of `Product`, it must be `Product[]`. You'd need to use Javascript [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform the `Product[]` array.
3. You're also missing the Typescript [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to make the actual conversion to another type.

Try the following

```js
getData(): Observable<IdName[]> {
  return this.productService.getProducts().pipe(
    map((products: Product[]) =>            // <-- no return here, this is RxJS `map` operator 
      products.map((product: Product) => {  // <-- Javascript `Array#map` function
        return { 
          id: product.id, 
          name: product.name 
        } as IdName;                        // <-- assert type using Typescript `as`
      })
    )                                       // <-- no semi-colon here
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I am still getting "A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value. (alias) interface IdName import IdName" error.

Comment: Found it, just have to add return this.productService.getProduct()... Thanks for the explanations. Very useful information.

Comment: @developer: I've updated the answer to include the `return`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use a function here? You can assign this to a variable of type `Observable<IdName>`. Also, you still need to map through each product inside the emitted array.

```
this.getData$ = this.productService.getProducts().pipe(
  map(products=>
    products.map({id, name}) => ({id, name}) as IdName)
  )
)
```

A couple of things to note:

- The `map()` operator will infer the type being emitted from a strongly typed observable, so you don't need to re-declare products as `Product[]`.
- Object deconstruction is your friend when you only need to reference certain properties of an object. This is why the array map is referencing `({id, name})`